# Multiple equation numbering style in a document

Tags: equations, cross-referencing, numbering

I'm using book class. In my case some chapter contains sections and some others do not. I would like to express equation number in the following way:

1) If the chapter contains sections I would like the equation number to be like this `(section.equation)` [notice: *no chapter*];

2) If the chapter does not contain any section `(equation)`.

Of course I would like to have the same in the reference number. Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\numberwithin{equation}{section}
\renewcommand{\theequation}{\arabic{section}.\arabic{equation}}
 \chapter{First}
 \section{First First}
 \begin{equation}\label{eq:1}
 E=\gamma m
 \end{equation}
 \section{First Second}
 \begin{equation}\label{eq:2}
 0=0
 \end{equation}
 \chapter{Second}
 \numberwithin{equation}{chapter}
 \renewcommand{\theequation}{\arabic{equation}}
 \begin{equation}\label{eq:3}
 e^{i\pi}+1=0
 \end{equation}
 \chapter{Third}
 \begin{equation}\label{eq:4}
 f(w) = \frac{1}{2i\pi}\oint_{C_w}\frac{f(z)\mathrm{d}z}{z-w}
 \end{equation}
 \chapter{Last}
 \eqref{eq:1}, \eqref{eq:2}, \eqref{eq:3}, \eqref{eq:4}
\end{document}
```

I get the wanted result

## BUT

I don't want to switch manually between cases 1) and 2) i.e. I don't want to write explicitly `\numberwithing` command nor redefine `\theequation`. I would like LaTeX to do it compile-time:

a) it realize if the chapter contains any saction;

b) if yes the equation numbering is case 1);

c) if not is case 2).

Comment: How is the determination of "realize if the chapter contains any saction" supposed to be achieved? Does your document contain chapters with "delayed" sections, i.e., chapters that contains one or more `equation`-like environments *before* the first `\section` directive is encountered?

Comment: Sounds like to be a task for `xcntperchap` package to determine how many sections there are in a document...

Comment: How is numbered equation in a case when chapter contain sections but some equations are before first section?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\numberwithin{equation}{section}
\renewcommand{\theequation}{\ifnum\value{section}>0 \arabic{section}.\fi\arabic{equation}}
 \chapter{First}
 \section{First First}
 \begin{equation}\label{eq:1}
 E=\gamma m
 \end{equation}
 \section{First Second}
 \begin{equation}\label{eq:2}
 0=0
 \end{equation}
 \chapter{Second}
 \begin{equation}\label{eq:3}
 e^{i\pi}+1=0
 \end{equation}
 \chapter{Third}
 \begin{equation}\label{eq:4}
 f(w) = \frac{1}{2i\pi}\oint_{C_w}\frac{f(z)\mathrm{d}z}{z-w}
 \end{equation}
 \chapter{Last}
 \eqref{eq:1}, \eqref{eq:2}, \eqref{eq:3}, \eqref{eq:4}
\end{document}
```

Comment: If I understand correctly the question (and to me only the following has a sense) than `\renewcommand{\theequation}{\arabic{chapter}.\ifnum\value{section}>0 \arabic{section}.\fi\arabic{equation}}` ...

Comment: @Zarko the Op explictly says that chapter is to be omitted, doesn't it?

Comment: yes, you have right. This is so unusual request (and lead to inconsistency in a book navigation) that I overlooked it. Sorry for noise.

Comment: @Zarko Now I can explain why this so unusual request: I would like to do a "research diary" in order to get rid of notebooks and bloks. My idea is that every chapter is a day in which I write all the computation I'm doing and also comments on paper I'm reading. So the number of the chapter becomes something strange (just a day counter), it would be more useful to substitute the number of the day with the date itself i.e. `(1)_{20 Apr 17}` for the number of the equation.

Answer (score 3):

With `etoolbox`:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\usepackage{etoolbox, chngcntr}
\counterwithin*{equation}{section}}
\renewcommand{\theequation}{\ifnumcomp{\value{section}}{=}{0}{}{\arabic{section}.}\arabic{equation}}

\begin{document}

 \chapter{First}
 \section{First First}
 \begin{equation}\label{eq:1}
 E=\gamma m
 \end{equation}
 \section{First Second}
 \begin{equation}\label{eq:2}
 0=0
 \end{equation}

  \chapter{Second}
 \begin{equation}\label{eq:3}
 e^{i\pi}+1=0
 \end{equation}

 \chapter{Third}
 \begin{equation}\label{eq:4}
 f(w) = \frac{1}{2i\pi}\oint_{C_w}\frac{f(z)\mathrm{d}z}{z-w}
 \end{equation}

 \chapter{Last}
 \eqref{eq:1}, \eqref{eq:2}, \eqref{eq:3}, \eqref{eq:4}

 \end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I would do the following (regardless that request is different (which to my opinion lead to be lost in book navigation):

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\numberwithin{equation}{section}
\renewcommand{\theequation}{\ifnum\value{section}>0
                                \thesection-\arabic{equation}%
                            \else
                                \thechapter-\arabic{equation}%
                            \fi}

\begin{document}

 \chapter{One}
 \section{First section in the first chaper}
 \begin{equation}\label{eq:1}
 E=\gamma m
 \end{equation}
 \section{Second section in the first chapter}
 \begin{equation}\label{eq:2}
 0=0
 \end{equation}

 \chapter{Two}
 \begin{equation}\label{eq:3}
 e^{i\pi}+1=0
 \end{equation}

 \chapter{Three}
 \begin{equation}\label{eq:4}
 f(w) = \frac{1}{2i\pi}\oint_{C_w}\frac{f(z)\mathrm{d}z}{z-w}
 \end{equation}

 \section{First section in third chapter}
 \begin{equation}\label{eq:5}
 E=\gamma m
 \end{equation}

 \chapter{four}
 \eqref{eq:1}, \eqref{eq:2}, \eqref{eq:3}, \eqref{eq:4} and \eqref{eq:5}
\end{document}
```

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SQpW]3.png